# Creative telescoping of a non-hypergeometric function $\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}A_{n,k}/\left[(1+A_{n,k})(b+cA_{n,k})(q+pA_{n,k})\right]$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, telescopic-series

I have been struggling with finding an analytic form for the following expression:
$$
a_n=\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}A_{n,k}\left[(1+A_{n,k})(1-q+(1-p)A_{n,k})(q+pA_{n,k})\right]^{-1}
$$
where $A_{n,k}=(\frac{p}{q})^k(\frac{1-p}{1-q})^{n-k}$ and $0<q<p<1$.

**EDIT 2:
I am editing the question to being interested in $\sum\limits_{n=0}^m a_n$** so that I may accept @mathlove 's second answer, which is the one which (imo) makes the most progress in the desired direction (end of EDIT 2)

In fact, I am also interested in $\sum\limits_{m=1}^M\frac12-(p-q)^2\sum\limits_{n=0}^m a_n$ (because the limit $\lim\limits_{m\to\infty}(p-q)^2\sum\limits_{n=0}^m a_n=\frac12$, which I "know" numerically), with $M$ being some number or potentially going to $\infty$ (because, from what I can tell numerically, this series converges, see [this Wolfram notebook](https://www.wolframcloud.com/env/scardinetwolf3/stackexchange.nb)). I say this in case solving for one of these sums is actually simpler, but I believe that I will be able to figure this out if I can make some headway on $a_n$ itself.

So far, I have stumbled on this website onto a few references to the book A=B, and the term of "creative telescoping". Unfortunately, after scanning the book, I am led to believe that the algorithms for such telescoping do not work in this case since the function is not (unless I am mistaken) hypergeometric. However, I am hopeful that some other type of creative telescoping would work here, just there is, as far as I can tell, no universal way of achieving this here and so far I have not found any way to do so.

The main issue seems to reside in the portion that is on the denominator (the term in brackets to the $-1$ power), which has $1+x$ terms inside which are causing me a headache because it prevents the usual technique of simplifying the powers when searching for a recurrence by expressing it as a ratio of two successive terms. If we call that term in brackets $F_{n,k}$, I think it could be interesting to find a recurrence over it, but so far I have failed to find one. I have tried expressing it as a function of $F_{n-1,k-1}$ and $F_{n,k-1}$ but no success this way so far. I also tried writing the ratio $F_{n,k}/F_{n-1,k-1}$, by using logs, but so far this is a dead end.

Any suggestions on paths forward would be appreciated!

PS: although I am dealing in discrete sums, if any continuous results do exists I am also interested as I can perhaps make some connections that way.

== Edit 1 ==

@mathlove, in their derivations here and in a related post, introduce $D_{n,k}=\left(\dfrac{1}{p}\right)^k\left(\dfrac{1}{1-p}\right)^{n-k}+\left(\dfrac{1}{q}\right)^k\left(\dfrac{1}{1-q}\right)^{n-k}$. By working on solving $a_n$, I get to (I hope this is correct but it seems to check out):
$$
a_n=\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}\frac{1}{D_{n,k}}-\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n+1}\binom{n+1}{k}\frac{1}{D_{n+1,k}}
$$
It is tempting to think that this would telescope, but the fact that $D_{n,k}$ is on the denominator has me struggling...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a nice idea in Edit 1.

This answer proves the following claims :

**Claim 1** : $\ \ a_n=\dfrac{1}{(q-p)^2}(G_n-G_{n+1})$ where $G_n=\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom nk\dfrac{1}{D_{n,k}}$

**Claim 2** : $\ \ \displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{m}a_n=\frac{1}{(q-p)^2}\bigg(\frac 12-G_{m+1}\bigg)$

**Claim 3** : $\ \ \displaystyle\lim_{m\to\infty}(p-q)^2\sum_{n=0}^{m}a_n=\dfrac 12$

**Claim 4** : $\ \ \displaystyle\frac{(q+1-p)^2}{2(p-q)}\lt\lim_{M\to\infty}\sum_{m=1}^{M}\bigg(\frac 12-(p-q)^2\sum_{n=0}^{m}a_n\bigg)\leqslant \frac{(\sqrt{pq}+\sqrt{(1-p)(1-q)})^2}{2(1-\sqrt{pq}-\sqrt{(1-p)(1-q)})}$

---

**Claim 1** : $\ \ a_n=\dfrac{1}{(q-p)^2}(G_n-G_{n+1})$ where $G_n=\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom nk\dfrac{1}{D_{n,k}}$

*Proof* :

We have
$$\begin{align}a_n&=\frac{1-p}{(q-p)^2}e_n-\frac{b_n}{(q-p)^2}
\\\\&=\frac{1-p}{(q-p)^2}\bigg(\frac{1}{1-p}-\frac{1}{1-p}\sum_{k=0}^{n+1}\binom{n+1}{k}\frac{1}{D_{n+1,k}}\bigg)
\\&\qquad\quad -\frac{1}{(q-p)^2}\bigg(1-\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom nk\frac{1}{D_{n,k}}\bigg)
\\\\&=\frac{1}{(q-p)^2}(G_n-G_{n+1})\end{align}$$

where $b_n=\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom nkp^k(1-p)^{n-k}\frac{A_{n,k}}{A_{n,k}+1}$.

---

**Claim 2** : $\ \ \displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{m}a_n=\frac{1}{(q-p)^2}\bigg(\frac 12-G_{m+1}\bigg)$

*Proof* :

$$\begin{align}\sum_{n=0}^{m}a_n&=\frac{1}{(q-p)^2}\sum_{n=0}^{m}(G_n-G_{n+1})
\\\\&=\frac{1}{(q-p)^2}(G_0-G_{m+1})
\\\\&=\frac{1}{(q-p)^2}\bigg(\frac 12-G_{m+1}\bigg)\end{align}$$

---

**Claim 3** : $\ \ \displaystyle\lim_{m\to\infty}(p-q)^2\sum_{n=0}^{m}a_n=\dfrac 12$

*Proof* :

[This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4675541/78967) shows that $\displaystyle\lim_{m\to\infty}G_{m+1}=\lim_{m\to\infty}(1-b_{m+1})=0$.

Therefore, we have
$$\lim_{m\to\infty}(p-q)^2\sum_{n=0}^{m}a_n=\lim_{m\to\infty}\bigg(\frac 12-G_{m+1}\bigg)=\frac 12$$

---

**Claim 4** : $\ \ \displaystyle\frac{(q+1-p)^2}{2(p-q)}\lt\lim_{M\to\infty}\sum_{m=1}^{M}\bigg(\frac 12-(p-q)^2\sum_{n=0}^{m}a_n\bigg)\leqslant \frac{(\sqrt{pq}+\sqrt{(1-p)(1-q)})^2}{2(1-\sqrt{pq}-\sqrt{(1-p)(1-q)})}$

*Proof* :

We have
$$\begin{align}\sum_{m=1}^{M}\bigg(\frac 12-(q-p)^2\sum_{n=0}^{m}a_n\bigg)&=\sum_{m=1}^{M}G_{m+1}\end{align}$$
Then, we have
$$\sum_{m=1}^{M}G_{m+1}\gt\sum_{m=1}^{M}\frac 12C^{m+1}=\frac{C^2-C^{M+2}}{2(1-C)}$$
and
$$\sum_{m=1}^{M}G_{m+1}\leqslant\sum_{m=1}^{M}\frac 12B^{m+1}=\frac{B^2-B^{M+2}}{2(1-B)}$$
where $B=\sqrt{pq}+\sqrt{(1-p)(1-q)}$ and $C=q+1-p$.

The claims follows from these.

Comment: Thanks! Claim 2 is so surprising as it relates both questions of mine in an unexpected manner. Whereas the other post was an attempt at calculating a simpler term, it turns out that whatever that term is (which is still open) is equal to the sum of the more complicated term from the present question. Very unexpected, but I confirm this is true. I must still make some time to study claim 4.

Comment: Although this is not an answer to the a priori simpler (and original) question, this is a very elegant solution to a side problem which is perhaps even more useful. I am thus hesitating to reformulate my original question so that this could be the answer, and studying the side question $\sum\limits_{m=1}^M\frac12-(p-q)^2\sum\limits_{n=0}^m a_n$ in a new post (if I cannot solve it on my own with these new elements)...

Answer (score 2):

This answer proves that $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=0$ and that $\displaystyle\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{N}(1-a_n)=\infty$.

*Proof* :

Using the result of marty cohen's answer, we have
$$
a_n=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\dfrac{\binom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}A_{n,k}}{(1+A_{n,k})(1-q+(1-p)A_{n,k})(q+pA_{n,k})}
$$
$$=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\dfrac{\binom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}A_{n,k}}{(q-p)^2}\left(\dfrac{p^2}{p A_{n,k} + q} - \dfrac{(p - 1)^2}{(p - 1) A_{n,k} + q - 1} - \dfrac1{A_{n,k} + 1}\right)
$$

$$=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\underbrace{\dfrac{\binom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}A_{n,k}}{(q-p)^2}\left(\dfrac{p^2}{p A_{n,k} + q} - \dfrac{(p - 1)^2}{(p - 1) A_{n,k} + q - 1}\right)}_{c_n} - \frac{b_n}{(p-q)^2}
$$
where $b_n=\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom nkp^k(1-p)^{n-k}\frac{A_{n,k}}{A_{n,k}+1}$. [This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4675541/78967) proves that $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}b_n=1$.

Here, noting that

$$\frac{q(1-p)}{p(1-q)}A_{n,k+1}=A_{n,k}$$
$$\frac{q}{1-q}\bigg(1-q+(1-p)A_{n,k+1}\bigg)=q+pA_{n,k}$$

we have

$$\begin{align}c_n&=\dfrac{\binom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}A_{n,k}}{(q-p)^2}\left(\dfrac{\frac{p^2(1-q)}{q}}{1-q+(1-p)A_{n,k+1}} + \dfrac{(p - 1)^2}{1-q+(1-p) A_{n,k}}\right)
\\\\&=\dfrac{\frac{p^2(1-q)}{q}\cdot\dfrac{\binom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}\frac{q(1-p)}{p(1-q)}A_{n,k+1}}{(q-p)^2}}{1-q+(1-p)A_{n,k+1}} + \dfrac{(p - 1)^2\dfrac{\binom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}A_{n,k}}{(q-p)^2}}{1-q+(1-p) A_{n,k}} 
\\\\&=\dfrac{\dfrac{\binom{n}{k}p^{k+1}(1-p)^{n+1-k}A_{n,k+1}}{(q-p)^2}}{1-q+(1-p)A_{n,k+1}} + \dfrac{\dfrac{\binom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{n+2-k}A_{n,k}}{(q-p)^2}}{1-q+(1-p) A_{n,k}} 
\\\\&=\binom nk(d_{n,k+1}+d_{n,k})\end{align}$$

where
$$d_{n,k}=\dfrac{\dfrac{p^k(1-p)^{n+2-k}A_{n,k}}{(q-p)^2}}{1-q+(1-p) A_{n,k}}$$

Using $\binom{N}{r}=\binom{N-1}{r-1}+\binom{N-1}{r}$, we have
$$\begin{align}\sum_{k=0}^{n}c_n&=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom nk\bigg(d_{n,k+1}+ d_{n,k}\bigg)
\\\\&=\binom n0d_{n,0}+\bigg(\sum_{k=1}^{n}\bigg(\binom{n}{k-1}+\binom nk\bigg)d_{n,k}\bigg)+\binom nnd_{n,n+1}
\\\\&=\sum_{k=0}^{n+1}\binom{n+1}{k}d_{n,k}
\\\\&=\frac{1}{(q-p)^2}\sum_{k=0}^{n+1}\binom{n+1}{k}\dfrac{p^k(1-p)^{n+2-k}A_{n,k}}{1-q+(1-p) A_{n,k}}
\\\\&=\frac{1-p}{(q-p)^2}\underbrace{\sum_{k=0}^{n+1}\binom{n+1}{k}\dfrac{p^k(1-p)^{n+1-k}(\frac{p}{q})^k(\frac{1-p}{1-q})^{n-k}}{1-q+(1-p) (\frac{p}{q})^k(\frac{1-p}{1-q})^{n-k}}}_{e_n}\end{align}$$

Now, let us consider $\dfrac{1}{1-p}-e_n$.

$$\begin{align}\frac{1}{1-p}-e_n&=\sum_{k=0}^{n+1}\binom{n+1}{k}p^k(1-p)^{n+1-k}\frac{1}{1-p}
\\&\qquad -\sum_{k=0}^{n+1}\binom{n+1}{k}\dfrac{p^k(1-p)^{n+1-k}(\frac{p}{q})^k(\frac{1-p}{1-q})^{n-k}}{1-q+(1-p) (\frac{p}{q})^k(\frac{1-p}{1-q})^{n-k}}
\\\\&=\sum_{k=0}^{n+1}\binom{n+1}{k}\dfrac{p^k(1-p)^{n+1-k}\frac{1-q}{1-p}}{1-q+(1-p) (\frac{p}{q})^k(\frac{1-p}{1-q})^{n-k}}
\\\\&=\frac{1}{1-p}\sum_{k=0}^{n+1}\binom{n+1}{k}\dfrac{1}{D}\end{align}$$

where

$$D=\bigg(\frac{1}{p}\bigg)^k\bigg(\frac{1}{1-p}\bigg)^{n+1-k}+\bigg(\frac{1}{q}\bigg)^k\bigg(\frac{1}{1-q}\bigg)^{n+1-k}$$

Since $\dfrac 1p\lt \dfrac 1q$ and $\dfrac{1}{1-q}\lt\dfrac{1}{1-p}$, we get $D\lt 2\left(\dfrac{1}{q}\right)^k\left(\dfrac{1}{1-p}\right)^{n+1-k}$ from which we have
$$\frac{1}{1-p}-e_n\gt \frac{1}{2(1-p)}(q+1-p)^{n+1}\tag1$$

Next, using $\dfrac{2}{\dfrac{1}{a}+\dfrac 1b}\leqslant \sqrt{ab}$, i.e. $\dfrac{1}{a+b}\leqslant\dfrac 12(ab)^{-\frac 12}$, we get
$$\frac 1D\leqslant \frac 12\bigg(\bigg(\frac{1}{pq}\bigg)^k\bigg(\frac{1}{(1-p)(1-q)}\bigg)^{n+1-k}\bigg)^{-\frac 12}$$
i.e.
$$\frac 1D\leqslant \frac 12\bigg(\sqrt{pq}\bigg)^k\bigg(\sqrt{(1-p)(1-q)}\bigg)^{n+1-k}$$
from which we have
$$\frac{1}{1-p}-e_n\leqslant \frac{1}{2(1-p)}\bigg(\sqrt{pq}+\sqrt{(1-p)(1-q)}\bigg)^{n+1}\tag2$$

Since $0\lt q+1-p\lt 1$ and $0\lt \sqrt{pq}+\sqrt{(1-p)(1-q)}\lt 1$, we get, from $(1)(2)$,  $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}e_n=\frac{1}{1-p}$.

Therefore, we finally get
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=\lim_{n\to\infty}\bigg(\frac{1-p}{(p-q)^2}e_n-\frac{b_n}{(p-q)^2}\bigg)=0$$

---

In the following, let us prove that $\displaystyle\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{N}(1-a_n)=\infty$.

We have
$$1-\frac 12B^n\leqslant b_n\lt 1-\frac 12C^n$$
and
$$\frac{1}{1-p}-\frac{1}{2(1-p)}B^{n+1}\leqslant e_n\lt \frac{1}{1-p}-\frac{1}{2(1-p)}C^{n+1}$$
where $B=\sqrt{pq}+\sqrt{(1-p)(1-q)}$ and $C=q+1-p$.

So,
$$\sum_{n=1}^{N}(1-a_n)\gt \sum_{n=1}^{N}\bigg(1-\frac{1-p}{(p-q)^2}\bigg(\frac{1}{1-p}-\frac{1}{2(1-p)}C^{n+1}\bigg)+\frac{1}{(p-q)^2}\bigg(1-\frac 12B^n\bigg)\bigg)$$

$$=\sum_{n=1}^{N}\bigg(1+\frac{C^{n+1}}{2(p-q)^2}-\frac{B^n}{2(p-q)^2}\bigg)$$

Since
$$\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{N}\bigg(1+\frac{C^{n+1}}{2(p-q)^2}-\frac{B^n}{2(p-q)^2}\bigg)=\infty$$
we finally get
$$\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{N}(1-a_n)=\infty$$

---

**Added 1** :

> There must be a problem somewhere (when I say "somewhere", that includes on my end) because, as I stated and as far as I can tell with the choices of $p$ and $q$ I have tried so far, the series $\displaystyle\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{N}(1−a_n)$ converges numerically for $0<q<p<1$.

Let us take $q=\frac 15$ and $p=\frac 45$.

WolframAlpha gives the followings :

- $a_1\approx 0.23529411764$
- $a_2\approx 0.18316742081$
- $a_3\approx 0.11438350617$
- $a_4\approx 0.09170369833$
- $a_5\approx 0.06139304418$
- $a_6\approx 0.04992997170$
- $a_7\approx 0.03451152357$
- $a_8\approx 0.02830677081$
- $a_9\approx 0.01992934589$
- $a_{10}\approx 0.0164383$ (see [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=sum%5B%28%28%28C%2810%2Ck%29%29*%28%280.8%29%5Ek%29*%28%280.2%29%5E%2810-k%29%29*%28+%284%5Ek%29*%28%281%2F4%29%5E%2810-k%29%29%29%29%2F%28%281%2B%28+%284%5Ek%29*%28%281%2F4%29%5E%2810-k%29%29%29%29%280.8%2B%280.2%29*%28%284%5Ek%29*%28%281%2F4%29%5E%2810-k%29%29%29%29%280.2%2B0.8*%28+%284%5Ek%29*%28%281%2F4%29%5E%2810-k%29%29%29%29%29%29%2C%7Bk%2C0%2C10%7D%5D))
- $a_{100}\approx 1.04532460 × 10^{-11}$ (see [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=sum%5B%28%28%28C%28100%2Ck%29%29*%28%280.8%29%5Ek%29*%28%280.2%29%5E%28100-k%29%29*%28+%284%5Ek%29*%28%281%2F4%29%5E%28100-k%29%29%29%29%2F%28%281%2B%28+%284%5Ek%29*%28%281%2F4%29%5E%28100-k%29%29%29%29%280.8%2B%280.2%29*%28%284%5Ek%29*%28%281%2F4%29%5E%28100-k%29%29%29%29%280.2%2B0.8*%28+%284%5Ek%29*%28%281%2F4%29%5E%28100-k%29%29%29%29%29%29%2C%7Bk%2C0%2C100%7D%5D))
- $a_{1000}\approx 2.00942830 × 10^{-99}$ (see [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=sum%5B%28%28%28C%281000%2Ck%29%29*%28%280.8%29%5Ek%29*%28%280.2%29%5E%281000-k%29%29*%28+%284%5Ek%29*%28%281%2F4%29%5E%281000-k%29%29%29%29%2F%28%281%2B%28+%284%5Ek%29*%28%281%2F4%29%5E%281000-k%29%29%29%29%280.8%2B%280.2%29*%28%284%5Ek%29*%28%281%2F4%29%5E%281000-k%29%29%29%29%280.2%2B0.8*%28+%284%5Ek%29*%28%281%2F4%29%5E%281000-k%29%29%29%29%29%29%2C%7Bk%2C0%2C1000%7D%5D))

So, it seems that $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=0$ is correct.

Also, we have the followings :

- $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{1}(1−a_n)\approx 0.76470588236$
- $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{2}(1−a_n)\approx 1.58153846155$
- $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{3}(1−a_n)\approx 2.46715495538$
- $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{4}(1−a_n)\approx 3.37545125705$
- $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{5}(1−a_n)\approx 4.31405821287$
- $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{6}(1−a_n)\approx 5.26412824117$
- $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{7}(1−a_n)\approx 6.2296167176$
- $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{8}(1−a_n)\approx 7.20130994679$
- $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{9}(1−a_n)\approx 8.1813806009$
- $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{10}(1−a_n)\approx 9.1649423009$

Considering $a_{100}\approx 1.04532460 × 10^{-11}$ and $a_{1000}\approx 2.00942830 × 10^{-99}$, it seems that $\displaystyle\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{N}(1−a_n)=\infty$ is correct.

---

**Added 2** :

Let $T(M):=\displaystyle\sum_{m=1}^M\bigg(\frac 12-\sum_{n=0}^{m}a_n\bigg)$. Then, for $q=\frac 15$ and $p=\frac 45$, I got the followings :

- $T(1)=\frac 12-a_0-a_1$$\approx -0.23529411764$
- $T(2)=1-2a_0-2a_1-a_2$$\approx -0.65375565609$
- $T(3)=\frac 32-3a_0-3a_1-2a_2-a_3$$\approx -1.18660070071$.

So, it seems that $T(M)$ is decreasing, which is very different from the plot in your comment below.

Comment: Thanks! There must be a problem somewhere (when I say "somewhere", that includes on my end) because, as I stated and as far as I can tell with the choices of p and q I have tried so far, the series $\lim\limits_{N\to\infty}\sum\limits_{n=1}^N(1-a_n)$ converges numerically for $0<q<p<1$.

Comment: See what I added. I wrote what I got from WolframAlpha. It seems that both $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=0$ and $\displaystyle\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{N}(1-a_n)=\infty$ are correct. Try $q=\frac 15$ and $p=\frac 45$ to see if you get the same results.

Comment: You are correct that $a_n$ goes to zero. I have edited the side-question as it was mistated (it was subsidiary to the main question and I was less careful about its statement since I did not think it would be the first focus, I do apologize), but I am in fact interested in the sum $\sum\limits_{m=1}^M\left[\frac12-\sum\limits_{n=0}^m a_n\right]$, which is the one that converges. This should be apparent by looking at these Wolfram plots:
https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/da418b83-dc8e-4c19-9083-ce0569199be6

Comment: I am attributing the bounty to your answer since it is the most helpful so far, thank you. But I will be offering a new one for the corrected statement and the answer to the original post, which is still open.

Comment: @sg1234 : See what I added. It seems that $\displaystyle\sum_{m=1}^M\bigg(\frac 12-\sum_{n=0}^{m}a_n\bigg)$ is decreasing.

Comment: @sg1234 : Your a[n_] in the Wolfram plots is different from our $a_n$. (There is $(p-q)^2$ which should be excluded.)

Comment: well spotted, thanks! In fact, the limit of $(p-q)^2\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n$ is 1/2, which is useful for finding my sum, so I edited my question (rather than changing the notebook) to make that more clear. I did not include that to start with because it is just a constant, but if the summation is being worked on then it is necessary to make that distinction. Given all these specificities, I am wondering if the summation portion should be pushed to another question. I do not want to spam this site with too many facets of the same question, but if it is deemed better then I will do so.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possible start
(with help from Wolfram Alpha):

$\dfrac1{(1+ax)(1+bx)(1+cx)}
=\dfrac{a^2}{(a - b) (a - c) (a x + 1)} - \dfrac{b^2}{(a - b) (b - c) (b x + 1)} - \dfrac{c^2}{(a - c) (c - b) (c x + 1)}
$

so

$\begin{array}\\
\dfrac1{(1+x)(1-q+(1-p)x)(q+px)}
&=\dfrac{p^2}{(q - p)^2 (p x + q)} - \dfrac{(p - 1)^2}{(q - p)^2 ((p - 1) x + q - 1)} - \dfrac1{(x + 1) (q - p)^2}\\
&=\dfrac1{(q-p)^2}\left(\dfrac{p^2}{p x + q} - \dfrac{(p - 1)^2}{(p - 1) x + q - 1} - \dfrac1{x + 1}\right)\\
\end{array}
$

You might be able to get some
telescoping from this.

Comment: Thanks! That's a good idea, but I cannot see, even for the simplest of terms $\frac{x}{1+x}$, how it would be telescoped. The problem is that the simplification which usually arises (at least in the examples I have seen) does not work here since the powers (in the $x$ term, i.e. the $A_{n,k}$) do not cancel out when I write the ratio of two successive terms. It's likely there are other telescoping methods I am not aware of, and perhaps one of those works in this situation?