# Calculating $\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}\frac{(\frac{p}{q})^k(\frac{1-p}{1-q})^{n-k}}{1+(\frac{p}{q})^k(\frac{1-p}{1-q})^{n-k}}$

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients

I am trying to find the analytical form to this sum:
$$
a_n=\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}\dfrac{\left(\dfrac{p}{q}\right)^k\left(\dfrac{1-p}{1-q}\right)^{n-k}}{1+\left(\dfrac{p}{q}\right)^k\left(\dfrac{1-p}{1-q}\right)^{n-k}}
$$
where $0<q<p<1$.

Edit: following the comment by @dezdichado, an equivalent form is:
$$
1-a_n=\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}\dfrac{1}{1+\left(\dfrac{p}{q}\right)^k\left(\dfrac{1-p}{1-q}\right)^{n-k}}\\
=\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}\dfrac{1}{\left(\dfrac{1}{p}\right)^k\left(\dfrac{1}{1-p}\right)^{n-k}+\left(\dfrac{1}{q}\right)^k\left(\dfrac{1}{1-q}\right)^{n-k}}
$$

What I have tried so far was using a log in the hopes of writing ratios of successive terms such that a recursion could be found (I have found this suggestion by scanning the book A=B, on the subject of creative telescoping). Unfortunately that has not brought much light to my problem, so I am looking for other avenues which might lead me to a solution.

== Edit 2 ==

Following the suggestion by @Thomas-Andrews, I have plugged in a few numbers but nothing glaring comes out. However, the special case $p=1-q$ is interesting and leads to the following simplification, in which I use the inequality between harmonic and geometric means (I believe I am correct in what I wrote, but not 100% sure):
$$
1-a_n=\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}\dfrac{1}{\left(\dfrac{1}{p}\right)^k\left(\dfrac{1}{1-p}\right)^{n-k}+\left(\dfrac{1}{1-p}\right)^k\left(\dfrac{1}{p}\right)^{n-k}}\le(2p(1-p))^n
$$

I am not sure this will be good enough, but I am willing to try if I can also find a lower bound (this is because I have multiple such terms, some which are added and others subtracted, therefore I need both an upper and lower bound to make sure the total is still bounded at least on one side). [I am not sure if this search for a lower bound warrants a new and different sub-question, but I will leave this here for now in case someone more knowledgeable about how this works decides to edit this portion of the question.]

In [another post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4670933/creative-telescoping-of-a-non-hypergeometric-function-sum-k-0n-binomnkp), I try to calculate a more complex version of this sum. A person suggested an idea which yields me to believe that if I could solve the simpler problem posed here, I might be able to solve the other more complex sum using further steps.

Comment: Have you tried specific numerical values of $p,q,n?$

Comment: at least subtract $1-a_n$ and simplify the summand to: 
$$\dfrac{1}{1 + \text{stuff with p,q}}$$

Comment: and essentially your sum is then equivalent to:
$$\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}\frac{1}{\left(\frac{1}{p}\right)^k\left(\frac{1}{1-p}\right)^{n-k}+\left(\frac{1}{q}\right)^k\left(\frac{1}{1-q}\right)^{n-k}}$$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews although I have played with many parameters numerically for my more general problem, I have not tried plugging specific numbers in the hopes of calculating this sum, no.

Comment: @dezdichado thanks, you are correct and I have added those in an edit to my question. The last form you wrote is reminiscent of a harmonic mean, I wonder if that's something to chew on. Aside from that, the ratio of successive terms, which is the tool I am currently exploring for telescoping, is still elusive, unless I am not seeing something more obvious?

Comment: My gut feeling is no closed form exists. You get a half whenever p and q are equal. Maybe simplify for small values of n and see if it's generalizable

Comment: A somewhat nicer form, IMO, is $$\sum_{k=0}^n\binom nk \dfrac{p^k(1-p)^{n-k}q^k(1-q)^{n-k}}{p^k(1-p)^{n-k} + q^k(1-q)^{n-k}}$$
or
$$\sum_{k=0}^n\binom nk \dfrac1{p^{-k}(1-p)^{k-n} + q^{-k}(1-q)^{k-n}}$$though the latter is just your final form with negative exponents.

Comment: PaulSinclair thanks for those: although nicer, I find them less inspiring than @dezdichado 's form which makes the harmonic mean appear. This leads me to a second-best approach, which is finding bounds. Given the harmonic mean is bounded above by the geometric mean, this yields a closed upper bound. Does anyone see a lower bound with a closed form in this case?

Comment: @PaulSinclair thanks, as I mentioned above the "uglier" version is actually useful to me since it is reminiscent of the harmonic mean, which I now use in an edited version of my question to try to find bounds in the special case p=1-q.

Comment: It might be useful to do a Taylor expansion about $\frac12$. (Just a suggestion - I haven't tried it.) Or you might use the symmetry inherent in the formula to group terms and reduce the sum to $k \le \frac n2$.

Answer (score 2):

You said "I need both an upper and lower bound".

This answer proves that
$$1-\frac 12\bigg(\sqrt{pq}+\sqrt{(1-p)(1-q)}\bigg)^n\leqslant a_n\lt 1-\frac 12(q+1-p)^n$$
from which $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=1$ follows.

*Proof* :

You have $\displaystyle 1-a_n=\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}\dfrac{1}{D}$
where
$$D=\left(\dfrac{1}{p}\right)^k\left(\dfrac{1}{1-p}\right)^{n-k}+\left(\dfrac{1}{q}\right)^k\left(\dfrac{1}{1-q}\right)^{n-k}$$

Since $\dfrac 1p\lt \dfrac 1q$ and $\dfrac{1}{1-q}\lt\dfrac{1}{1-p}$, we get $D\lt 2\left(\dfrac{1}{q}\right)^k\left(\dfrac{1}{1-p}\right)^{n-k}$ from which we have
$$1-a_n\gt \frac 12(q+1-p)^n\tag1$$

Next, using $\dfrac{2}{\dfrac{1}{a}+\dfrac 1b}\leqslant \sqrt{ab}$, i.e. $\dfrac{1}{a+b}\leqslant\dfrac 12(ab)^{-\frac 12}$, we get
$$\frac 1D\leqslant \frac 12\bigg(\bigg(\frac{1}{pq}\bigg)^k\bigg(\frac{1}{(1-p)(1-q)}\bigg)^{n-k}\bigg)^{-\frac 12}$$
i.e.
$$\frac 1D\leqslant \frac 12\bigg(\sqrt{pq}\bigg)^k\bigg(\sqrt{(1-p)(1-q)}\bigg)^{n-k}$$
from which we have
$$1-a_n\leqslant \frac 12\bigg(\sqrt{pq}+\sqrt{(1-p)(1-q)}\bigg)^n\tag2$$

Therefore, it follows from $(1)(2)$ that
$$1-\frac 12\bigg(\sqrt{pq}+\sqrt{(1-p)(1-q)}\bigg)^n\leqslant a_n\lt 1-\frac 12(q+1-p)^n\tag3$$

Here, $\sqrt{pq}+\sqrt{(1-p)(1-q)}\lt 1$ holds since it is equivalent to

$$\bigg(\sqrt{(1-p)(1-q)}\bigg)^2\lt (1-\sqrt{pq})^2\iff (\sqrt p-\sqrt q)^2\gt 0$$
which is true.

Since $0\lt q+1-p\lt 1$ and $0\lt \sqrt{pq}+\sqrt{(1-p)(1-q)}\lt 1$, we get, from $(3)$, $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=1$.

Comment: Thanks! This is promising, there is quite a bit for me to chew on here so let me study this and report back soon.

Comment: Although this was helpful for a number of reasons (including developments in the related answer referenced), these bounds unfortunately are insufficient for calculating values of $a_n$ or obtaining the sort of insights about the evolution of $a_n$ I was hoping would be possible. So I am back at the original problem of calculating $a_n$, with some advancement on the problem that I am about to include in an edit to the other post.

Comment: @sg1234 : You are right that this answer is insufficient for obtaining $\displaystyle \lim_{M\to\infty}\sum_{m=1}^{M}\bigg(\frac 12-(p-q)^2\sum_{n=0}^{m}a_n\bigg)$$\displaystyle=\lim_{M\to\infty}\sum_{m=1}^{M}\sum_{k=0}^{m+1}\binom{m+1}{k}\dfrac{1}{D_{m+1,k}}$. I've been trying to find it, but I got only some small results. Anyway, in the other post, I summarized some small results which I got using your nice idea.

Comment: thanks: your other answer looks pretty amazing actually, though I am still digesting it / checking things out (my numerical results do not agree, but I must double check as I was already wrong a few times when doing such checks). Since the active bounty is currently on this question, I am attributing it to you, but I am hoping to gain more rep points to be able to show you my gratitude in the other post soon. Thanks so much for not giving up, and I will post any results / advances on my end soon I hope.